# When I hide a button and unhide the button, another duplicate button is added in tkinter. How to fix this?

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]Functionality: When I click "Music theory" button, I want it to show another button ("Sight reading" button) and when I click "Music theory" button again, I want the "Sight reading button to hide.

Inside  musictheorysubbtns() I'm able to hide the dropdown optionmenu when I click the "Sight reading" button. I tried doing the same for the "music theory button thats outside the function and it added two buttons on the window. I'm able to hide it but when I click "music theory button again, it adds 2 more duplicate buttons, now in total 4 buttons.

How to fix this?

```
...
tab6 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab6, text="Music")
tabControl.pack(expand=5, fill='both')

musicbtnsframe = tk.Frame(tab6)
musicbtnsframe.pack(side='top')

mtheorysubbtsframe = tk.Frame(tab6)
mtheorysubbtsframe.pack(anchor='center')

mtdropdownframe = tk.Frame(tab6)
mtdropdownframe.pack(anchor='center')

mrefreshingframe = tk.Frame(tab6)
mrefreshingframe.pack(anchor='center')

def musictheorysubbtns():
    def mtheorydrops():
        mtheory_opt = mtdropdown
        mtheory_opt.config(width=50, font=('Helvetica', 12))
        mtheory_opt.pack()   
    def mtheory_images(mt):
        print(mt)  # selected option
        mt_label.config(image=mtimgz[mt])
    mt_label = tk.Label(mtdropdownframe)
    mt_label.pack(side = 'bottom', pady=padylength)
    mtimgz = {}
    for mtimgz_name in tradinglists.retracements:
        mtimgz[mtimgz_name] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./Images/{}.png".format(mtimgz_name)))
    mtvariable = tk.StringVar(tab2)
    mtvariable.set(tradinglists.retracements[0])
    mtdropdown = tk.OptionMenu(mtdropdownframe, mtvariable, *tradinglists.retracements, command=mtheory_images)
    def refreshmtsub():
        mtdropdownframe.pack_forget() if mtdropdownframe.winfo_manager() else mtdropdownframe.pack(anchor='center')
    mtheory_k = tk.Button(mtheorysubbtsframe, text="Sight reading", width = artbtn_width, height = btnsize_height, command=lambda:[mtheorydrops(), refreshmtsub()])
    mtheory_k.pack(side = 'left', padx=padxwidth, pady=padylength)

def refreshmt():
        mtheorysubbtsframe.pack_forget() if mtheorysubbtsframe.winfo_manager() else mtheorysubbtsframe.pack(anchor='center')
        

theory_k = tk.Button(musicbtnsframe, text="Music theory", width = btnsize_width, height = btnsize_height, command=lambda:[musictheorysubbtns(), refreshmt()])
theory_k.pack(side='left', padx=padxwidth, pady=padylength)
```

v2:

```
tab6 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab6, text="Music")
tabControl.pack(expand=5, fill='both')

class ShowHideButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, target_widget, *args, **kwargs):
        self.target = target_widget
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.config(command=self.toggle)
    def toggle(self, force_off = False):
        if force_off or self.target.winfo_manager():
            self.target.pack_forget()
        else:
            self.target.pack()
        if isinstance(self.target, ShowHideButton):
            self.target.toggle(force_off=True)

musicbtnsframe = tk.Frame(tab6)
musicbtnsframe.pack(side='top')
mt_sub_frame = tk.Frame(tab6)
mt_sub_frame.pack(side='top')
mt_SRframe = tk.Frame(tab6)
mt_SRframe.pack(anchor='center')
mt_compframe = tk.Frame(tab6)
mt_compframe.pack(anchor='center')


def mt_images(m1t):
    print(m1t)  # selected option
    mt_label.config(image=mtimgz[m1t])
mt_label = tk.Label(mt_SRframe)
mt_label.pack(side = 'bottom', pady=padylength)
mtimgz = {}
for mt_name in musiclists.sightReaing:
    mtimgz[mt_name] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(importImageWithResize("./Music_images/Sightreading/{}.png".format(mt_name)))
mtvar = tk.StringVar(tab2)
mtvar.set(musiclists.sightReaing[0])
mt = tk.OptionMenu(mt_SRframe, mtvar, *musiclists.sightReaing, command=mt_images)
mt_opt = mt
mt_opt.config(width=50, font=('Helvetica', 12))
mt_opt.pack()   

def mtcomp_images(mtcomp1t):
    print(mtcomp1t)  # selected option
    mtcomp_label.config(image=mtcompimgz[mtcomp1t])
mtcomp_label = tk.Label(mt_compframe)
mtcomp_label.pack(side = 'bottom', pady=padylength)
mtcompimgz = {}
for mtcomp_name in musiclists.composition:
    mtcompimgz[mtcomp_name] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(importImageWithResize("./Music_images/Composition/{}.png".format(mtcomp_name)))
mtcompvar = tk.StringVar(tab2)
mtcompvar.set(musiclists.composition[0])
mtcomp = tk.OptionMenu(mt_compframe, mtcompvar, *musiclists.composition, command=mtcomp_images)
mtcomp_opt = mtcomp
mtcomp_opt.config(width=50, font=('Helvetica', 12))
mtcomp_opt.pack()   

def mt_sub_btns():
    theory_k_sightreading_k = ShowHideButton(mt_sub_frame, mt_opt, text='Sight Reading')
    theory_k_composition_k = ShowHideButton(mt_sub_frame, mtcomp_opt, text='Composition')
theory_k = ShowHideButton(musicbtnsframe, mt_sub_btns, text='Music theory')
theory_k.pack(side='left', padx=padxwidth, pady=padylength)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about the question... Are you looking for how to show/hide a button and ALSO how to get your OptionMenu's to show and hide in certain situations?

Comment: Hey sorry for the confusion! Yes, I want it show/hide a button first and then show/hide OptionMenu. What I'm planning to achieve is the following tree structure would: Button >  Multiple Buttons > Option menu for each button which has the show/hide option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want functionality added to a feature in tkinter, it is usually best to customize the widgets to do what you need instead of stringing together functionality.  Let me show you what I mean with an example.  Since you want one button that show/hides another button, and another button that show/hides an optionmenu, it sounds like it would be best for you to have buttons that show/hide other widgets.
To do this, make your own version of a button:

```
import tkinter as tk

class ShowHideButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, target_widget, *args, **kwargs):
        self.target = target_widget
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.config(command=self.toggle)
```

The `ShowHideButton` is our custom name of our new widget.  The `(tk.Button)` says which widget we are basing it off of.
The `__init__` method (that's init with two underscores on each side) is what happens right when you make this widget.  The parameters we put in there basically all need to be there.  `self` is just required for python reasons, `parent` and `*args, **kwargs` are things that `tk.Button` needs, but `target_widget` is just something I added to be the target of our show/hide tools.
`self.target = target_widget` saves the widget we pass through the parameters to the instance of our button.
The line that starts with 'super' makes python run tk.Button's **init** method so it will build everything that is needed to be a button.  (Which is good because I am trying to take tkinter's button widget and adjust it to fit our needs.)
The last line sets the command of the button to a function called `self.toggle`.  Since this happens, you will never need to set the command of our buttons.  In fact, we want our buttons to hide/show some other widget, and the whole purpose is to have that functionality built in so it wouldn't make sense to manually set the command.
Put this under the init method to define what self.toggle does:

```
    def toggle(self):
        if or self.target.winfo_manager():
            self.target.pack_forget()
        else:
            self.target.pack()
```

That should be the same indentation level as the init method.  You can probably see what this does.  It checks if `self.target` is packed or not and then changes it.
If you use this, you may notice something kind of strange:  if you hide a widget, and that widget had opened something, it leaves that something packed.  If you would like it to pass down hides, change it to be something like this:

```
    def toggle(self, force_off = False):
        if force_off or self.target.winfo_manager():
            self.target.pack_forget()
        else:
            self.target.pack()
        if isinstance(self.target, ShowHideButton):
            self.target.toggle(force_off=True)
```

This will check if the target is itself a `ShowHideButton` and then turn it off as well if it is.

Here is my whole test script to demo the new button:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class ShowHideButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, target_widget, *args, **kwargs):
        self.target = target_widget
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.config(command=self.toggle)
    def toggle(self, force_off = False):
        if force_off or self.target.winfo_manager():
            self.target.pack_forget()
        else:
            self.target.pack()
        if isinstance(self.target, ShowHideButton):
            self.target.toggle(force_off=True)

my_option_value = tk.StringVar()
my_option_value.set('opt1')
my_option_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, my_option_value, 'opt1', 'opt2', 'etc')
s_r_button = ShowHideButton(root, my_option_menu, text='Sight Reading')
m_t_button = ShowHideButton(root, s_r_button, text='Music theory')
m_t_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can just copy and paste that class-block into your code and start using ShowHideButtons like they are any other widget.  Note the order that I made the buttons in the demo above though.  They need to have their targets when you make them so you have to make the ones that are targets before the ones that target them.

This could also be adapted to use grid or place instead of pack.  Really, you can modify tkinter widgets in any way you like.  Let us know if you have any other questions etc.

EDIT:  if you would like a version of this where you can have more than one item being toggled by the button, here you go:

```
class ShowHideButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, target_widgets, *args, **kwargs):
        self.targets = target_widgets
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.config(command=self.toggle)
    def toggle(self, force_off = False):
        for i in self.targets:
            if force_off or i.winfo_manager():
                i.pack_forget()
            else:
                i.pack()
            if isinstance(i, ShowHideButton):
                self.target.toggle(force_off=True)
```

Note that you must make `target_widgets` an iterable item (like a list or tuple) in this case.  If you use this version but only want one widget to toggle, you can make a single-length list by surrounding the name of it by [ ].

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for the explanation. I tried using the ```showhidebutton```. There are 2 issues I'm facing after using it: 
1. The image from the dropdown is not being hidden when I click the _Sight reading_ button.
2. How can I add multiple buttons under _music theory_ button? I tried putting the 2 sub-buttons in a function and then assigning it to the main _Music theory_ button. It gave me an error:   
```if force_off or self.target.winfo_manager():
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'winfo_manager'```

Comment: Also should I put all four section sections (button, sub buttons, dropdown, image displayed from dropdown) in the same frame?

Comment: I think you've got the right idea.  That showhidebutton class, only supports one thing being hidden and shown (and that is why putting in two gave you an error), but if you make that one thing a Frame that has multiple things packed in to it, it would show and hide all of them together.    The image you are having issues with is the same problem actually.  Put it in a frame with the other things you want it to show and hide and it should come with it.  If you want to to be able to freely add more than one widget to the class without frames, let me know, and I'll try to rewrite it like that

Comment: Ah ok! I figured thats where I was messing up. Can you please rewrite the class without frames. It would help alot!

Comment: Hey! So I updated my post with what I have so far. Also attached a screenshot of what Im seeing as soon as I run the program. I see both the dropdowns even without click on the "music theory button". Also when I click the "Music theory" button, nothing happens.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a version of ShowHideButton where you put in a list of widgets instead of just one.  The problem you're seeing where you see the dropdowns is happening because you are packing them.  Things only show when they are packed (that is why the ShowHideButton's command packs them to show them.)  The reason your 'music theory' button doesn't work is because you put a method name in for the target_widget instead of the widget you want to toggle.

Comment: I was able to fix the dropdown showing issue and making the button work. I'm just a little confused about where you said put the widgets in a list. I tried doing that but I think I'm doing it wrong?
Is the following what you meant?
`subbtns=[ShowHideButton(musicbtnsframe, mt_opt, text='Sight Reading'),ShowHideButton(musicbtnsframe, mtcomp_opt, text='Composition')]

theory_k = ShowHideButton(musicbtnsframe, subbtns, text='Music theory')
theory_k.pack(side='left', padx=padxwidth, pady=padylength)`

Comment: That's basically right.  I usually make all the items I want in list and then do something like `listname = [first_item, second_item, third_item, etc]` or if it makes more sense for the code, I will make an empty list `listname = []` and then use `listname.append(my_new_item)` whenever I made new items that need to be in the list.  Then, when you need a button that toggles everything in that list, `ShowHideButton(root, listname, text='suchnsuch')`

Comment: So I tried doing that and got an error similar to my first comment. I replace the showbutton class with the updated one.
`if force_off or self.target.winfo_manager():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'winfo_manager'`

Comment: That error is happening because you are still using the single-target version of ShowHideButton.  Remember when I said "I have edited my answer to include a version of ShowHideButton where you put in a list of widgets instead of just one."  You are going to need to actually change your code to have that in it if you want to use its functionality.

Comment: I'm completely lost as I'm still learning python. I tried couple of different methods for the last hour or so and kept getting few different errors. I also tried using a for loop something like `tw = []
 for i in tw: 
  i.append()`. Didn't get any working result. This is what I last tried `class ShowHideButton(tk.Button):
    a = tk.Button
    b = tk.Button
    tw = [a, b]
    def __init__(self, parent, tw, *args, **kwargs):
        self.target = tw`

Comment: I fear you may be biting off more than you can chew.  Start from the full example I gave and try to adjust that to your needs.  Or you may want to step back and make simpler programs so you can learn the basics and come back to this project later

Comment: You're right. Thanks for your input and feedback! I appreciate your time